# Explanation of ne and eq methods

Tags: python

I just want confirmation that i have understood this right:

This compares two objects and returns true if they are the same:

```
   def __eq__(self, other):
       return  self.__dict__ == other.__dict__
```

This compares two objects and returns True if the objects are not the same:

```
def __ne__(self,other):
    return not self == other
```

Have i understood this or am I wrong?

Comment: That's correct. You understood it right

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct. It is similar to calling:

```
def __ne__(self,other):
    return not self.__eq__(other)

# `self == other` makes call to `self.__eq__(other)`
```